# Is there an open source AVFoundation implementation of the MPMoviePlayerController view?

Tags: ios, open-source, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

Our current iOS project requires localization of video assets.  We are currently handling this by localizing only the audio track of each video.  From there we are using AVFoundation to add the localized audio track to to the assest.  This is working well.  We add the video and audio as separate asset tracks and the audio track is localized to the users locale.

Our issue is we want the controls of the video (play button, scrubber, etc..) to look and feel like the MPMoviePlayerController video player.  Before we code this from scratch, is there an open source implementation of the MPMoviePlayerController video player that uses that uses AVFoundation (top toolbar with scrubber and done button, lower controls view with play button and volume)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://bitbucket.org/brentsimmons/ngmovieplayer/

Note: the repository linked above has been removed; you can try with a similar project (with identical name) at https://github.com/Natthaphong/NGMoviePlayer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I generally agree, but he or she is asking about an open source project. I don't see how can I extract the essential part of a multiple class complex project. But, feel free to downvote, it's your right.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe I was a little too quick with my review.

Comment: This is a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an `AVMutableComposition`. You can look through [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_EditingAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH6-SW1) and if you need any help with it let me know. I would gladly help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I already have the multiple language audio tracks working..its more that I was looking for a view (maybe an example xib) that is _styled_ much like the default video player so we do not have to build it from scratch.